# Нужно получить следующее за найденным слово

Tags: python

Из 1С получены данные.
Мне нужно вынуть данные для бота по каждому действующему счетчику. Например, по номеру счетчика получается только первое значение

```
Результат:
{
    "dataType": "data_for_bot",
    "data": [
        {
            "balance": 657.26
        },
        {
            "fullName": «Сидоров И.П.»
        },
        {
            "metersData": [
                {
                    "serialNumber": "738362",
                    "unit": "куб.м.",
                    "name": "гор.вода",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "id": "496703a4-0668-11ec-8102-00155d393ce6",
                    "lastReading": "14,12",
                    "lastReadingDate": "28.02.2022 0:00:00",
                    "scale": "0",
                    "meterType": "hotWater",
                },
                {
                    "serialNumber": "00507723",
                    "unit": "куб.м.",
                    "name": "горячая вода  ",
                    "state": "Не действует",
                    "id": "36a7b4a3-b9b1-11e9-80e6-00155de4bdf6",
                    "lastReading": "20",
                    "lastReadingDate": "30.06.2021 0:00:00",
                    "scale": "0",
                    "meterType": "hotWater",
                },
                {
                    "serialNumber": "8091855",
                    "unit": "",
                    "name": "горячая вода",
                    "state": "Не действует",
                    "id": "2c84bfa1-87fd-11e3-8ac8-000476f87573",
                    "lastReading": "383",
                    "lastReadingDate": "26.07.2019 0:00:00",
                    "scale": "0",
                    "meterType": "hotWater",
                },
                {
                    "serialNumber": "00505818",
                    "unit": "куб.м.",
                    "name": "холодная вода ",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "id": "1bb4d89b-b9b1-11e9-80e6-00155de4bdf6",
                    "lastReading": "346",
                    "lastReadingDate": "27.01.2022 0:00:00",
                    "scale": "0",
                    "meterType": "coldWater",
                },
                {
                    "serialNumber": "01538380",
                    "unit": "",
                    "name": "электросчетчик",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "id": "b87bcaec-8800-11e3-8ac8-000476f87573",
                    "lastReading": "37 310",
                    "lastReadingDate": "18.05.2022 0:00:00",
                    "scale": "6",
                    "meterType": "electricity",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Код:

````
page = page1с.split()
water = '"serialNumber":'
for w in page:
    n = w.find(water)
    index_v = -1
    if n != -1:
        index_v = page.index(water)
        number_water = page[index_v + 1]
        print('Номер счетчика: '  + number_water)```
````

Вывод:

```
Номер счетчика: 738362,
Номер счетчика: 738362,
Номер счетчика: 738362,
Номер счетчика: 738362,
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: На входе есть Результат из 1С  
На выходе ожидаю:   
Номер счетчика: 738362,  
Номер счетчика: 00505818  
Ошибки нет, но выводит номер счетчика не верно, повторяя только первый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {"data": [
        {"metersData": [
                {
                    "serialNumber": "738362",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "lastReading": "259,12",
                    "lastReadingDate": "28.02.2022 0:00:00"
                },
                {   
                    "serialNumber": "738014",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "lastReading": "296,12",
                    "lastReadingDate": "28.02.2022 0:00:00"
                },
                {   
                    "serialNumber": "83781910",
                    "state": "Не действует",
                    "lastReading": "9,395",
                    "lastReadingDate": "30.04.2014 0:00:00"
                },
                {   
                    "serialNumber": "728380",
                    "state": "Действует",
                    "lastReading": "256,08",
                    "lastReadingDate": "28.02.2022 0:00:00"
                }]}]}

result = []

for i in data.get('data')[0].get('metersData'):
    if i.get('state') == 'Действует':
        number = i.get('serialNumber')
        last_reading = i.get('lastReading')
        last_reading_date = i.get('lastReadingDate')
        result.append(f'Номер счетчика: {number}\nПоследние показания: {last_reading}\nДата последнего чтения: {last_reading_date}')

print(result)
```

['Номер счетчика: 738362\nПоследние показания: 259,12\nДата последнего чтения: 28.02.2022 0:00:00', 'Номер счетчика: 738014\nПоследние показания: 296,12\nДата последнего чтения: 28.02.2022 0:00:00', 'Номер счетчика: 728380\nПоследние показания: 256,08\nДата последнего чтения: 28.02.2022 0:00:00']

Comment: Спасибо, только у меня не получается правильно data прописать

Comment: Пришли полностью что из 1С приходит

Comment: Разобралась, спасибо